# Why does this always return "undefined"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

The following code always returns "undefined"

```
function sendCommand(cmdJson){
    chrome.extension.sendRequest(cmdJson, function(response){
        return response;
    });
}
```

I've also tried this variant with the same result

```
function sendCommand(cmdJson){
    var msg;
    chrome.extension.sendRequest(cmdJson, function(response){
        msg = response;
    });
    return msg;
}
```

If I do an `alert(response);` instead of `return response;` I get the expected value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing that `chrome.extension.sendRequest` is asynchronous, in which case `sendCommand` doesn't return anything. The response-handler *inside* `sendCommand` is the one that returns something, but that's not the same, as `sendCommand` returning something. So when you call `sendCommand` it returns `undefined`.

Basically, `sendCommand` invokes the `chrome.extension.sendRequest` function, and then returns `undefined` right away, while the `chrome.extension.sendRequest` function is still running.

There's no real way to make something asynchronous behave synchronously - it's better to restructure your code.

Comment: ok I thought `chrome.extension.sendRequest(cmdJson, function(response){}` would block while it waited for the response.

Comment: @ZeroDivide Well, I admit that I don't know the Chrome Extension API, but judging from the behavior you're describing, I'd say it's a fair bet that `sendRequest` is asynchronous.

Comment: Yeah its how contentscripts (injected into webpages) talks with an extension's background script(one script running in the background). I guess I'll just assume that it succeeds instead of passing the response back to the calling function.

Comment: @ZeroDivide: sendRequest indeed does not block--it and most other similar API functions in the Chrome API are asynchronous. You're going to have to rely on the callback to call another piece of code and notify it that it has succeeded or failed.

Comment: @ZeroDivide Assuming it to succeed sounds fragile to me, but it's your call. You could look into Deferred/Promises/Futures patterns. Or simply skip your `sendCommand` function, and call `sendRequest` directly, and proceed when you get a response

Comment: Yeah I'm looking at some design patterns now. I have a bunch of different commands that I will be sending. Some will respond with JSON  objects while others simply respond with success or failure. I want a system that can pass the command to the background script and respond appropriately once the command is completed.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely because you are performing an ajax call, which is asynchronous by nature.  An asynchronous function cannot return a value since there is no way to know when the asynchronous call will complete.

If you are using jQuery, you have two alternative options to get around this problem.  If you are using jQuery 1.5 or later, then you can use Deferred Objects.  Deferred Objects are a new object that jQuery allows you to use to interact with asynchronous code.

By default, a jquery ajax function (i.e. $.ajax, $.get, $.post, $.getJSON) returns a Deferred Object, so all you have to do is store your ajax call in a variable and then call available methods listed in the jQuery Deferred Object api.  Here is one of the best tutorials I have seen on jQuery Deferred Objects.  http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/using-deferreds-in-jquery/

```
var sendResponse = $.get("/getResponse");

//Somewhere else in your code
sendResponse.success(function(response) {
    return response;
});
```

The other options is to make your jquery ajax call synchronous.  You can do this by setting the **async** ajax property to **false**.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "someURL",
    async: false
});
```